# How can I update full description on Docker Hub automatically?

Tags: docker, travis-ci, docker-registry, dockerhub

I'm using Travis CI for building docker images from Dockerfiles and then pushing them to the Docker Hub on success.

I've created an MD file describing the image and how to use it. I want to have the same description on the Docker Hub in the full description section.

As I may update the description in the future, I want to have Travis CI automatically update the description based on the MD file in the repository with the new image.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Since the [Docker Hub does not expose any API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker-io_api/), the only way to send stuff to the Docker Hub remotely is with the `docker push` command, and this limits use to sending images.

On the other hand, if you let the Docker Hub service build your image for you from a Github or Bitbucket repository, then Docker Hub will update the long description by taking the content of the `README.md` file found on that  repository. See the [Understand the build process](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#understand-the-build-process) section from the Docker Hub's *Automated Build* documentation.

This implies that you host your *Dockerfile* and *README.md* files on Github or Bitbucket.

---

If you really need to first build your image on TravisCI (maybe because you also run automated tests on the built image), then you can have TravisCI trigger a webhook on Docker Hub to tell Docker Hub to build the image once TravisCI determined it was passing the tests.

To do so, in Docker Hub, configure your image as you would for *automated build* (hence associate a Github or Bitbucket project), but deactivate the automated feature:

> [image: Docker Hub project build settings]

Then scroll down on the *Build settings* page to the *Build Trigger* section and copy the trigger URL:

> [image: Docker Hub project build trigger]

Now edit your **.travis.yml** file and add the following block (mind the `<your account>` and `<your image>` placeholders):

```
after_success:
# notify Docker Hub to make a new build
- >
  [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ]
  && curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  --data '{"docker_tag_name": "latest"}'
  https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/<your account>/<your image>/trigger/$DOCKER_HUB_TOKEN/
```

Then go to your project page on the Travis CI website, and open the project settings:

> [image: Travis CI project settings]

And add the `DOCKER_HUB_TOKEN` environment variable to your Travis CI project with the trigger token value found on the Docker Hub Build Settings page:

> [image: Travis CI project environment variables]

You will still need a Github or Bitbucket repository associated to your Docker Hub project, but Travis CI will be the one to instruct Docker Hub when to build your image.

Comment: Yes, I know about Automated Builds, but I wanna use Travis CI, so that I can also do a bunch of tests. Is there any other way or should I just write a script acting as a browser and changing the description on Docker Hub page?

Comment: @NEO That can be done, the setup is more complicated but I'll try to explain it clearly → answer edited

Comment: This is in fact a good idea. But what should I do if I want to trigger multiple builds? Now, I'm using the build matrix feature of Travis CI to build multiple images by just changing some env variables. Is it possible to trigger builds per each row of the matrix?

Comment: You can't, Docker Hub has no idea about TravisCI. Those matrix settings are only known of TravisCI.
What can be done with Docker Hub is to have it build different branches of your repository and assign different tags to images produced from them. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/images/create-dialog.png in `Build Settings`

Comment: Docker Hub does expose an API. I think they just don't advertise it or provide official documentation. This is a good reference implementation that I've used in the past. https://github.com/RyanTheAllmighty/Docker-Hub-API

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can update it using API

```
local code=$(jq -n --arg msg "$(<README.md)" \
    '{"registry":"registry-1.docker.io","full_description": $msg }' | \
        curl -s -o /dev/null  -L -w "%{http_code}" \
           https://cloud.docker.com/v2/repositories/"${image}"/ \
           -d @- -X PATCH \
           -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
           -H "Authorization: JWT ${token}")
```

See details [here](https://github.com/moikot/golang-dep/blob/8234ce5a98f109d08fdc3ec2fac9a8e22b433a11/.travis/push.sh#L131)

Comment: The shell script has been moved to [moikot/docker-tools](https://github.com/moikot/docker-tools/blob/master/scripts.sh).

Answer (score 3):

I have a GitHub Action to do this.
https://github.com/peter-evans/dockerhub-description

```
    - name: Docker Hub Description
      uses: peter-evans/dockerhub-description@v2.1.0
      env:
        DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
        DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY: peterevans/dockerhub-description
```

You can also use it independently of GitHub Actions in other CI tools.

```
    docker run -v $PWD:/workspace \
      -e DOCKERHUB_USERNAME='user1' \
      -e DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD='xxxxx' \
      -e DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY='my-docker-image' \
      -e README_FILEPATH='/workspace/README.md' \
      peterevans/dockerhub-description:2.1.0
```

**Note:**  This does not work if you are using 2 Factor Authentication (2FA) and/or using Personal Access Tokens to authenticate to Docker Hub.  You must use your actual Docker Hub password.  See issue reported here: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1927

Answer (score 1):

you can use a docker container in your pipeline using this

https://hub.docker.com/r/sheogorath/readme-to-dockerhub

Project code

https://github.com/SISheogorath/readme-to-dockerhub

Gitlab CI Pipeline config looks like this

```
update-readme:
  stage: docs
  image:
    name: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/README.md:/data/README.md -e DOCKERHUB_USERNAME=$CI_REGISTRY_USER -e DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD=$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD -e DOCKERHUB_REPO_PREFIX=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE -e DOCKERHUB_REPO_NAME=$CONTAINER_NAME sheogorath/readme-to-dockerhub
```

Also I've got got a smaller command you can use as well, if you run this in the docker repo it will read `README.md` by default

```
  docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data/ aemdesign/dockerhub-description "$DOCKER_USERNAME" "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" aemdesign/dispatcher
```

If you want to specify manually run

```
  docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data/ aemdesign/dockerhub-description "$DOCKER_USERNAME" "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" aemdesign/dispatcher ./README.md
```

code: https://github.com/aem-design/docker-dockerhub-description

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Docker CLI plugin](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm) for updating the README on container registries (including Docker Hub). After installing it you can update the README on Dockerhub with:

```
docker pushrm myuser/myrepo
```

For CI it's also possible to run it as a [Docker container](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm#running-docker-pushrm-as-a-container) and there's [a github action](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm#use-with-github-actions) that wraps around it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a github action called [update-container-description](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/update-container-description-action)
that updates the description of a container repo on Docker Hub, Quay or Harbor from the README file of your github repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can only update your Docker Hub repository description by:

- Accessing the Hub API manually or via a helper job or container that accesses the API such as https://github.com/peter-evans/dockerhub-description.  **See authentication caveat below.**
- Use [Docker Hub Automated Builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/).

**Authentication Caveat** - You are no longer permitted to update certain resources, including repository description using Personal Access Tokens via the API.  You must use your actual Docker Hub password. See issue reported here: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1927
This effectively restricts the ability to use 2FA unless you choose Docker Hub Automated Builds.