# Updating Short and Full Descriptions on Docker Hub

Tags: docker, sbt, dockerhub

I am trying to add the short and full descriptions for my Docker image to my `build.sbt` file so that they will update on Docker Hub when I build and push a new image using [`sbt-native-packager`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) and its [`DockerPlugin`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html).

Currently (in addition to the usual stuff) I am specifying the following

```
// Specify Docker options
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
maintainer := "my-username <my-email-here>"
dockerRepository := Some("my-username")
packageSummary in Docker := "Why is this not showing up on Docker Hub?"
packageDescription in Docker := "Why is this not showing up on Docker Hub?"
```

...I then use the command...

```
sbt docker:publish
```

...to build and push the resulting image to Docker Hub. The image builds and updates without issue however the `packageSummary` and `packageDescription` information is not showing up on Docker Hub in the Short Description and Full Description respectively.

Perhaps I misunderstand the point of the `packageSummary` and the `packageDescription` fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sbt-native-packager's DockerPlugin [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) does not say anything about `packageSummary in Docker` and `packageDescription in Docker`.

It seems that this feature is not implemented. Moreover I do not know any mean that the Docker Hub provide to update the short description remotely, and the only mean I'm aware of to update the long description automatically is to [let Docker Hub build the image for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710937/107049).

Comment: Indeed.  I came across a few [examples](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/blob/master/docker/build.sbt) specifying these fields but didn't see any documentation on what they were supposed to be used for.  I then inferred that they should map into the Docker Hub fields. Apparently I was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so it might be a bit late to help the original poster's case, but for anyone else who finds this question, [dockerhub-description](https://github.com/peter-evans/dockerhub-description) GitHub Action can update the full description from README.md in workflows.

```
    - name: Docker Hub Description
      uses: peter-evans/dockerhub-description@v2.1.0
      env:
        DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
        DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
        DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY: peterevans/dockerhub-description
```

You can also use it independently of GitHub Actions in other CI tools.

```
    docker run -v $PWD:/workspace \
      -e DOCKERHUB_USERNAME='user1' \
      -e DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD='xxxxx' \
      -e DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY='my-docker-image' \
      -e README_FILEPATH='/workspace/README.md' \
      peterevans/dockerhub-description:2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late response, but you could use [docker pushrm](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm), a plugin for Docker to update the long description of container registries like Dockerhub from a local *README.md* file.